# Table with multiple columns error

Tags: tables

I've been working on the following table:

```
 \vspace{1mm}
 \begin{table}[hb]
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l}
    \cline{1-6}
    & & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\bf Annotator B} \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Yes & No \\ \cline{1-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\bf Annotator A} } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Yes} & $P_{1.} . P_{.1}$  & $P_{1.} . P_{.2}$  & $P_{1.}$   \\ \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{No} &  $P_{2.} . P_{.1}$  & $P_{2.} . P_{.2}$  & $P_{2.}$    \\ \cline{2-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
    \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} &  $P_{.1}$ & $P_{.2}$   \\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
```

It's currently producing this table:

[image]

I obviously want the cells with annotator a and b to have full borders but I can't seem to get it to work.  I've tried inserting \ \hline and modifying my cline's and no luck.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
 \begin{table}[hb]
    \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l}
        \cline{3-4}
        & & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\bf Annotator B} \\ \cline{3-4}
        & & Yes & No \\ \cline{1-5}
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\bf Annotator A} } & 
        \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Yes} & $P_{1.} . P_{.1}$  & $P_{1.} . P_{.2}$  & $P_{1.}$   \\ \cline{2-5}
         \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
         \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{No} &  $P_{2.} . P_{.1}$  & $P_{2.} . P_{.2}$  & $P_{2.}$    
         \\ \cline{2-5}
         \multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
         \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{} &  $P_{.1}$ & $P_{.2}$   
         \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

The problems were the first and last `\cline`.

**EDIT**. As asked in the comment:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|l}
\cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{\bf Annotator B} 
\\ \cline{3-4}
& & Yes & No \\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\multirow{2}{*}{\bf Annotator A} } & 
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{Yes} & $P_{1.} . P_{.1}$  & $P_{1.} . P_{.2}$  & $P_{1.}$   
\\ \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{ |c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{No} &  $P_{2.} . P_{.1}$  & $P_{2.} . P_{.2}$  & $P_{2.}$    
\\ \cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{1}{ c  }{}                        &
\multicolumn{1}{ c| }{} &  $P_{.1}$ & $P_{.2}$   \\ \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: how would you modify this so that the bottom of the cell containing annotator a would finish the same level as the bottom of the no cell?

Comment: @user47467 See my edited answer.